# What's the connecter type adapter to fit Nagoya NA-771G (SMA Male) to Baofeng UV-5R?

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r

I've got an antenna [Nagoya NA-771G](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B09WPXP5Z5) (SMA Male) what kind of connector adapter do I need to fit for my [Baofeng UV-5R](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B09GM4Y3RL)

Answer (score 2):

The Baofeng you have is also a male SMA connector. Ideally for a good physical fit without introducing extra strain/leverage on the connector you might consider getting an SMA female version of the antenna.

Otherwise you will need an female-female SMA adapter. Make sure *not* to get any "RP-SMA" ones that are also fairly common since they are used for WiFi equipment — those half-swap the gender between the center pin direction and the main shield/connection threading, and won't work.

You want just a normal/standard female SMA fitting on both ends of what is sometimes called a "barrel" adapter:

[image: A symmetrical female SMA adapter]

(Image source: https://www.ticarte.com/contenido/la-tarjeta-de-red-wifi-del-equipo-microinformatico)